# Regular Expression. Dreamweaver. Add Tag

Tags: regex, tags, dreamweaver

I have a very long law and need to make each ARTICLE strong to make it more readable. I came up with a regular expression in dreamweaver which finds the text a want to replace but I just don't know how to add the selector. The Find part works great, the problem is with the Replace.

ART. 1. Lorem Ipsum

ART. 12. Lorem Ipsum

ART. 345 Lorem Ipsum

I can select the section I want to make strong by using `ART. \d.`

QUESTION-> What do I have to put in Replace box to make it look like this?

**ART. 1.** Lorem Ipsum

**ART. 12.** Lorem Ipsum

**ART. 345** Lorem Ipsum

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in standard regex you would use something like:

```
/(ART\. \d+\.*)/<b>\1<\/b>/
```

i'm not really familiar with the dreamweaver replacement tool.